# Is there a way to refer to the previous page for the theme that was in effect there, and apply it to the current page when it loads, in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that sets the color theme of my site when clicked. The code works fine, but when I go to a different page on the site, it goes back to the original color theme. Is there a way to refer to the previous page's index for the theme that was in effect on that page, and apply it to this one when it loads, in JS?

Right now, if you visit a page, set the color theme, go to a different page, then go back to the first page, it remembers the theme and sets it automatically. However, you have to set it again every time you visit a new page.

Here's my code:

```
<a class="switch-light-blue" onclick="setTheme('theme-light-blue')"></a><a></a>

<script>
  // function to set a given theme/color-scheme
  function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
  }

  // Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
  (function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-light-blue') {
      setTheme('theme-light-blue');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: To save information about a page which is not currently open, you'll have to use some sort of data storage outside of JS, because JS is initialized every time a page loads. I would suggest you to use some JSON file in your server to save the current theme.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that? I've never worked with cookies before

Comment: You can do that without cookies as well. Just that you'll have to learn a bit of AJAX. Here's a [refercence article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1263247/How-to-Open-a-JSON-File-in-JavaScript-for-Web)